# Has anyone used Canon EF lenses on Sony mirrorless cameras?

Tags: lens, canon, sony, mirrorless

I'm looking to buy a Sony mirrorless camera. The draw back is the expense of extra lenses as Sony really is proud of their products. Has anyone here tried using a Canon EF lens on a Sony mirrorless camera? I'm looking at getting the a3000. I see that they make adapters but I have no idea if it's worth the effort. My budget has no room for a $1000 lens at the moment. I can however afford an adapter to make the canon lenses work on the Sony frame. I've found many used Canon lenses at pawn shops that are well within my budget.Thank you

Comment: Can you please describe exactly what you would like to get out of using a canon lens on a Sony camera (i.e. why not use Sigma or Tamron or any other off brand manufacturer's lenses, who make the lenses for manyu different mounts, and what about the canon lenses would make them worth the effort?)

Comment: I found several used Canon zoom lenses at pawn shops for under $100. I have to be very budget conscious. Most e mount Sony lenses are way beyond my budget for the time being. I can afford an adapter and a used Canon lens. I'm not opposed to using other glass with an adapter if the lenses are readily available and affordable. With that said, I suppose I can rent Sony lenses to get me by on the occasions that the kit lens will not be enough.